# Three js Blender exporter, how to specify type of texture

Tags: three.js

So my question is, when creating textures inside blender how can i configure those textures so that when I export mesh with Three.js exporter they get assigned as specific textures (map, aoMap).

So far I have one mesh with two textures and one textures is map(diffuse) and other texture is lightMap. ( That's what I figured out from generated .json file)

I want to set one texture to remain to be map, and another one to be aoMap insted of lightMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by looking at python scripts for Three.js exporter.

If you want texture to be map (diffuse) you need to set "Blend" property on texture inside Blender to be "Color". If you want texture to be map (light) you need to set texture "Blend" property inside blender to "Multiply".

It appears that exporter does not support map (ambient occlusion). I guess I will have to hack it up so it does.